# Preventing unauthorized key-listings

Tags: gnupg, identity

I just noticed that anyone who has root access to my computer can list the keys in my keyring. He would not be able to use any of my private keys without knowing the passphrase, but he could

1. examine the stored public keys and conclude who I communicate with
2. examine
   the private keys and conclude which identities belong to me

I tried to use an EncFS encrypted folder as my .gnupg folder, but the gpa frontend no longer works then.

What is the best way to avoid these issues?

Comment: Limit access to your computer? Once somebody has physical access (is logged in) to you computer all bets are off anyway. (He does not even have to be logged in to [destroy the computer](https://www.google.nl/search?q=usb+destroys+computer))

Answer (score 2):

Someone with root access could do any of these things anyways.  You cannot hide from root in unix-like OSes.  They have full control of the kernel, meaning they could, if they like, look at everything on any virtual terminal (ie, anything you type or see), examine any network traffic, examine process spaces - any OS level blocks can be bypassed by them - by patching the kernel, if by no other method.

Do not host your private keys anywhere you do not trust root.  If you do not trust root, you cannot trust the hardware, the OS, the shell, the applications...